# Issue with using Raster::reclassify with CropscapeR package data in Linux

Tags: r, linux, tiff, r-raster

I am using the package [CropscapeR](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/CropScapeR/versions/1.1.3) to get Cropland Data Layer (CDL) rasters. However, when I try to mask this raster using reclassify I sometimes run into issues. Since I am a Linux user (for R and OS specs see below), I have to do a distinct process to access the data than windows/mac users which involves the package httr and a tif file. This is the standard process recommended by the CropscapeR creator. If I then run `raster::reclassify` in my data, I have no problems. However, if I save the my RData and then reopen/restart R, and try to run `raster::reclassify`, it does not work. In particular, I get the following error message: `Error: C stack usage  7977940 is too close to the limit`. Also, I have a bunch of warnings of the sort:

```
    1: In new_CppObject_xp(fields$.module, fields$.pointer, ...) : 
    GDAL Error 4: /tmp/Rtmpf7yIsG/file28f21b32987a.tif: File or folder does not exist
```

Here is the code I am trying to run:

```
library(CropScapeR)    
library(httr)    
library(raster)    
library(sf)    

#Skip the SSL check    
httr::set_config(httr::config(ssl_verifypeer = 0L))    
#Automatically generate a temporary path to save the data    
tif_file <- tempfile(fileext = '.tif')    
#Download the raster TIF file into specified path, also read into R     
ST_CDL <- GetCDLData(aoi = '34007', year = 2021, type = 'f', save_path = tif_file)    

#The output file ST_CDL I get is a Formal class RasterLayer.    
#This is the way I am trying to mask the values of the raster I do not want.    
#Notice, again, that this code runs if I do it in sequence, I only get into    
#trouble if I first get ST_CDL, then save it as RData, reopen/restart R and     
#then try to run the code below directly without getting ST_CDL again through    
#the above process.

ST_CDL_blueberries <- 
  raster::reclassify(ST_CDL,
                     c(-0.1,241.9,NA,
                       242.1,255.1,NA),
                     progress="text")
```

**My specs:**

- Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
- R 4.2.1 (2022-06-23) -- "Funny-Looking Kid"
- RStudio 2022.07.2+576 "Spotted Wakerobin" Release (e7373ef832b49b2a9b88162cfe7eac5f22c40b34, 2022-09-06) for Ubuntu Jammy Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) QtWebEngine/5.12.8 Chrome/69.0.3497.128 Safari/537.36
- CropScapeR 1.1.4
- httr 1.4.4
- raster 3.6-3

Thanks for your help!

I got my data, saved it, restarted R and tried to run the code from there (without getting the data again). Supposedly this should work, but it did not.

Comment: Is your raster::reclassify(x, `rcl` a 3 or 2 column matrix? And why not just write out raster rather than RData...?

Comment: I remember getting a C stack error message a couple of weeks ago when doing something with reclassifying in `terra`. I don't remember the details of what I was doing. But apparently the error is the result of of a recursive operation that is happening somewhere inside the `terra` operation. Possibly the same thing is going for you? Sorry I can't remember any details to be of further help.

Comment: I generally assumed `tempfiles` were just that, temp, and perhaps as part of 'cleanup' upon ending a session they are purged, but some are and some not. But save yourself headaches and write out your rasters rather than `save(` toward an .RData

Comment: @Chris, thanks for your help. Writing and saving the raster indeed solves the problem!

Comment: As others are working with similar data, write up the approach you used to work with it successfully, as an answer, then accept your answer. Answered questions drive the bus. And you get points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by writing my raster. Namely, I did the following:

```
library(CropScapeR)    
library(httr)    
library(raster)    
library(sf)    

#Skip the SSL check    
httr::set_config(httr::config(ssl_verifypeer = 0L))    
#Automatically generate a temporary path to save the data    
tif_file <- tempfile(fileext = '.tif')    
#Download the raster TIF file into specified path, also read into R     
ST_CDL <- GetCDLData(aoi = '34007', year = 2021, type = 'f', save_path = tif_file)
#Now I write and save the raster, so it is available next time I open R
writeRaster(ST_CDL, "ST_CDL.tif", overwrite=TRUE)
ST_CDL = raster("ST_CDL.tif")  

ST_CDL_blueberries <- raster::reclassify(ST_CDL,
                 c(-0.1,241.9,NA,
                   242.1,255.1,NA),
                 progress="text")
```